# I need assistance in creating a function that will read (open new browser tab)url from CSV file in Java (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to learn java and selenium by myself and creating a robot that will scan job/career pages for certain string (job name e.g. QA , developer...)

I'm trying to create JAVA code using selenium, that will read URL links from CSV file and open a new tab.

the main goal is to add several url in the CSV and assert/locate a certain string in the designated url's for example: is there "Careers" link in each URL, the test will pass for this specific url.

1. created a selenium project
2. created new chromeDriver
3. Created CSV built from 3 columns (ID, company's name, URL) - and added it to the project

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class URLSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String fileName = "JobURLList.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);  //read from file

        try {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                System.out.println(data);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. first line in the CSV - titles: id, name, url
2. Read the url from the second line - e.g. https://careers.google.com/jobs/"
3. open browsertab and start going over the url list (from the CSV)
4. locate a hardcoded string (e.g. "developer" , "qa" ..) in each url
5. if such a string was found, write in console the url that the test turned out to be positive (such a string was found in one of the url's).
6. if no such string was found, skip to the next url.

Comment: I can't seems to add the full code that I have

Answer (score 0):

To open the new tab do something like this (this assumes "driver" object is your WebDriver):

```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');"); 

        Set<String> tab_handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        int number_of_tabs = tab_handles.size();
        int new_tab_index = number_of_tabs-1;
        driver.switchTo().window(tab_handles.toArray()[new_tab_index].toString());
```

You could then create a function that takes a list of key/value pairs, with URL and term to search for and loop through it.  Do you want to use a hashmap for this, or maybe an ArrayList of a class (id/name/url)?   The code for finding the text would be something like this (assumes you've defined a var of "Pass" to boolean):

```
   driver.get([var for URL]);
   //driver will wait for pageready state, so you may
   // not need the webdriver wait used below.  Depends
   // on if the page populates data after pagereadystate
      String xpather = "//*[contains(text(), '" + [string var for text to search for] + "')]";
        try
            {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            List<WebElement> element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpather)));   
        this.Pass = false;
        if (element.size() > 0)
        {
            this.Pass = true;

        }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Pass = false;
                System.out.println ("Exception finding text: " + ex.toString());
            }
```

Then logic for if (this.Pass==true or false)..